# How do I identify disk partitions from volume/UUID in Ubuntu File Manager (like /dev/sdx)?

Tags: linux, uuid, dev

Ubuntu "file manager" lists disk partition as "104 GB volume". "Properties" gives more information, but uses the disks UUID.

"Open on disks" just starts the "disks" application.

I like to operate on the partition, like move or resize it.

**How do I get my /dev/ name from the UUID?**

Preferably using a simple command.

Comment: Take a look at `/dev/disk/by-uuid` (e.g., `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid`).

Comment: Run `sudo blkid`.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve UUIDs to their full unix path use

```
sudo blkid
```

It will output something like this:

```
[root@EXAMPLE ~]# sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="12345678-dc78-4096-1111-c71111111111" TYPE="xfs"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="12345678-dc78-4096-1111-c71111111112" TYPE="xfs"
```

All the disk names will also be linked in the virtual directory `/dev/disk/by-uuid`.